# Как использовать ресурсные win dll  без WinAPI на C#?

Tags: c#

Есть приложение под винду на С#. Нужно портировать его на другие ОС (iOS/Android/WP/Linux/OS X), но есть одна проблема - данные оно хранит в ресурсных dll(unmanaged), вся работа с которыми ведется с помощью функций WinAPI(LoadLibrary(...),FindResource(...) и т.д.

Очевидно, что в таком виде код перенести невозможно, ведь в .NET рантаймах под другие платформы точно нету этого функционала. Но ведь, по сути, эти dll - просто файлы с данными. Может, кто-то в курсе, как можно работать с ними без WinAPI? Библиотека какая, или еще что...

Comment: Простите, а Вы слышали о таком слове как "кроссплатформенность"?

Comment: @MaxPovver, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: если будет дан - отмечу, конечно же

Answer (score 1):

Боюсь, что использовать win dll на iOS/Android/WP/Linux/OS X не так то просто. А вообще для этих целей можно использовать Mono/Wine, но для этого программа должна быть написана соответствующим образом. Подробнее читайте, например, [здесь.](http://habrahabr.ru/company/tiktokcoach/blog/204286/)

**Обновление**

Экспортируйте ресурсы из dll в отдельные файлы и используйте. Если боитесь огласки содержимого, то упакуйте их в зашифрованный zip.

Comment: хочу дополнительно отметить, что код из этих dll не нужен(если он там вообще есть), нужны только ресурсы

Comment: Обновил ответ